# Does things here mean materialistic things or does it have different context

Tags: quotes

It is good to love many things, for therein lies the true strength, and whosoever loves much performs much, and can accomplish much, and what is done in love is well done.
― Vincent Van Gogh
@Quoteitq

Comment: I'm guessing that this is likely a translation from Dutch; consulting the original would likely help to determine the exact meaning.

Comment: The question calls for an interpretation of one particular text, and providing that interpretation would not illuminate the meaning of the word *thing* in general - the OP seems to be already familiar with the range of meanings it has.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The context of love, performance and accomplishment in life suggests, to my ears anyway, a broad interpretation of 'things'. Those things could be physical and materialistic items, but would likely include themes like, for example, family and nature and beauty.